# Какой должен быть список параметров у обработчика TChromium.OnLoadError?

Tags: delphi, chromium

Делаю так:

```
procedure my_chromium.crmLoadError(Sender: TObject; const Browser: ICefBrowser;
  const frame: ICefFrame;  errorCode: integer;  const errorText, failedUrl: ustring  );
....
Chrom.OnLoadError := crmLoadError;
```

Ругается так:

> [Error] my_chromium.pas(132): Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'

Как правильно указать функцию, если страница загрузилась с ошибкой?

Comment: 1.Если у Вас есть исходники - нажмите `Ctrl` и кликните на OnLoadError, Вы перейдете к описанию класса, там можно увидеть описание типа. 2. Подведите курсор к `OnLoadError`. возможно появится всплывающее окно с осписением.

Comment: нифига никакого описания не нашел. нашел вобщем в чужих исходниках решение - выложу в ответ

Answer (score 0):

В общем нашел решение. Вот правильный список параметров:

```
procedure my_chromium.OnLoadError(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
      const frame: ICefFrame; errorCode: TCefHandlerErrorcode;
      const failedUrl: ustring; var errorText: ustring; out Result: Boolean);
```

Comment: А какой компонент и какой версии вы используете? Просто, у известного мне [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) этот callback объявлен [совсем не так](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/blob/7ba82bd5edb5b4c6fec65c4eeea0125d359e6c7e/source/uCEFChromiumEvents.pas#L68). И там объявление как раз соответствует тому, как у вас сделано в коде вопроса.

Comment: Странно, я использую Cef4Delphi и там вот так нужно объявлять:
procedure OnLoadError(const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame; errorCode: TCefErrorCode; const errorText, failedUrl: ustring);